# How to assign a jest mock function to a function within a React component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test using jest for my login component. How can I test that the handleLogin function is called on clicking the 'log in' button in the form, when the handLogin function is not passed to the Login component as a prop?

This is the code I currently have but I'm unsure how to assign the mockHandler to the handleLogin function.

Login.js :

```
const Login = () => {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const handleLogin = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        try {
                loginService.login({userName, password}) 
            setUserName('')
            setPassword('')
        } catch (exception) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Log in
            <form onSubmit = {handleLogin}>
                <div>
                    User name
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    value={userName}
                    autoComplete="on"
                    onChange = {({target}) => setUserName(target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    Password
                    <input
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    autoComplete="on"
                    onChange = {({target}) => setPassword(target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">log in</button>
                <div>
                    forgot password
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Login.test.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import Login from './Login'

test('clicking button calls event handler once', () => {
  const mockHandler = jest.fn()

  render(
    <Login handleLogin={mockHandler}/>
  )

  const user = userEvent.setup()
  const button = screen.getByText('log in')
  user.click(button)

  expect(mockHandler.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1)
})
```

But as the handleLogin is not passed as props this doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: **Don't** test the _implementation details_ (is the inputHandler function called?) - even if it wasn't bad practice, that function isn't exposed outside the component. Test the _behaviour_ (is the service method called with the right values? Are the inputs cleared?)

Answer (score 0):

For testing that a function was called by clicking a button

```
 describe('button field element methods', () => {
it('should trigger onClick function', async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn();//this is your mock function
    const { container } = render(<Button onClick={onClick} />);
    const vdsTag = container.querySelector('button');
    fireEvent.click(vdsTag); // this is how you programtically click a button
    expect(onClick).toBeCalled(); // this is how you expect a function to be called
    });
  });
});
```

So maybe change your code to:

```
 // import service mock function here
  // e.g. import {loginService} from './service';
  const loginSpy = jest.spyOn(loginService , 'login');
  const customTag=render(<Login />)
  const button = customTag.querySelector('button')
  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(loginSpy).toBeCalled();
  // You can also inject user name and pass, and make sure the spy 
  is called with these values
```

Comment: `<Login handleLogin={mockHandler}/>` - `handleLogin` is **not** a prop, as the OP says in the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah sorry. Will modify my answer then